# Increasing a parameter within a WordPress shortcode

Tags: javascript, wordpress, parameters

I'm using a Salon Booking System within Wordpress to develop an overview page. With this shortcode the reservations of today are displayed. I've also developed 2 buttons however, and i'd like for them to when pressed to go to the date of tomorrow. I've used this javascript code, but it doesn't work. How can i increment the value of days every time the button is pressed.

```
<p>[salon_booking_calendar days="1"]</p>
<button onclick="Volgende()" style="float: right;">Volgende</button>
<button onclick="Vorige()" style="float: left;">Vorige</button>

<script>
function volgende() {
[salon_booking_calendar days="+1"];
}
</script>
```

Comment: When you call a shortcode, you are generally outputting html. In this case, it looks like you are getting some output in your JS function, but no method for interacting with the dom in any way. What kind of errors do you see in your console? If the shortcode is returning a url, then you would need to change the window.location with that url:

    window.location="[salon_booking_calendar days="+1"]";

Or something like that.

Comment: @JamesHamann Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
(index):860 Uncaught ReferenceError: Volgende is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick // however i am getting no output in the browser itself.